# R.java not generating R.id in Android

Tags: android, android-xml, r.java-file

Maybe my Googling skills aren't the greatest, but whenever I Google this problem, I only find solutions to when the whole R file isn't generated which isn't my problem.  Everything else is generating just fine, however, there is no ID within R, so I have no way of referencing the views in my XML.  I've already tried project->clean, and restarting the adb server and eclipse, neither to any avail.  All help is greatly appreciated.  Below is my code.

```
public class MainMenu extends Activity {

    /*
     * Class member variables
     */
    private Button mMicrophoneButton;
    private ListView mMessageList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_menu_layout);
        setWidgets();
    }

    private void setWidgets() {
        this.mMicrophoneButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bMicrophone);
    }

}
```

Below is my XML, there's a lot of new stuff here that I don't recognize from previous projects I've done.  But I'm not finding any mistakes, which I know is usually the first cause of problems like this.:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainMenu"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/svMessageView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="9" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTest"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="test" />

    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bMicrophone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:minHeight="30dp"
        android:text="Speak Now" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: probably you are importing the wrong R

Comment: It's the only R in my workspace.  I see what you mean, but I don't think that's the case.  Especially because I've never had to explicitly import R in my Activities in my other android projects.  Eclipse is only underlining "id" from "R.id.bMicrophone" in red.  And I checked R, everything is there except the id nested class.

Comment: I don't know what you mean here, is this a new thing? That I have to use an actual import statement for R?  Eclipse recognizes R when I use it in MainMenu.java, so I don't think I need to.  Especially since I've never had to before.

Comment: check the R import and be sure it does not contains the android word

Comment: What do you mean by "che the R import"

Comment: @user1626655 paste the entire class file including the imports.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Make sure all of your files under res are building properly. Even if your R file is already generated it won't update if you have any errors.
- If you're referencing any library projects then you may have issues if there are any errors in that library project (src or res).
- In eclipse do a Project-->Clean on your project and all library projects it references.
- Delete gen folder and let eclipse auto generate it.

Comment: Yeah everything is building properly if I'm not mistaken.  By that I mean there are no red x's in any of my files within res.  The only files I have edited in the project are the ones I show in my question, and I am assuming all of the auto-generated stuff doesn't have errors.

Comment: Hmmm...that worked.  Just deleted the gen folder, then let eclipse create it.  Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

you need to save the xml file before cleaning the project for the ids to show up in R.java

Comment: This type of answers fit better as comments.

Answer (score 0):

I have Got the Same error but I got it solved by cleaning and rebuilding the project.

Actually, we can add Id there manually as well. I have done that couple of times.

But you can solve it by following the steps below

- Open the Android Studio
- Go to the Build
- Then Clean project
- after that Rebuild project

It will work definitely.